# Powershell Xml Attribute cast to concrete datatype

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the below simple xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot
  MyGuid="99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999"
  >
</MyRoot>
```

and code

```
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content "C:\myfile.xml"

    $unTypeVariable = $xml.MyRoot | Select MyGuid   

    Write-Host "unTypeVariable = '$unTypeVariable'"

    [GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable)
```

third line output:

```
unTypeVariable = '@{MyGuid=99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999}'
```

On the last line, I keep getting a cast exception (immediately below).  I *understand* it, but I don't know how to resolve it.

> Cannot convert the "@{MyGuid=99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999}"
>   value of type "Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement" to type "System.Guid".

I've tried:

```
    [GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable.Text)

    [GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable.Value)

    [GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable.InnerText)

    [GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable.'#text')
```

It's probably something stupid.

I'm not a powershell guru.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it with

```
$unTypeVariable = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//MyRoot').Attributes["MyGuid"].Value

[GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable)
```

And a coworker just sent me a message.

This will work too:

```
$unTypeVariable = $xml.MyRoot.MyGuid

[GUID]guidValue = [GUID]($unTypeVariable)
```